# How do I control the UIPageViewController itemIndex in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have set up a `UIPageViewController`. I therefore have two `UIViewControllers` and one `UIPageViewController`.

I am using this code and I would like to **decrease** or increase a variable called "character" when the user swipes **forward** or back.

```
class PageItemController: UIViewController {

/* As we’ll have only one class for all content controllers, we need to somehow identify different content items. In order to do it, each  PageItemController should have its index and image name.*/

var itemIndex: Int = 0 {

    didSet {
        if itemIndex == 0 {
            character = 1
        }
        if itemIndex == 1 {
            character = 2
        }
    }
}
...
}
```

What I am doing is:

1. Tap on the Check button to check the value of the variable "character"
2. **"Character 1" is being displayed**
3. Swipe to the right
4. Tap on the Check button to check the value of the variable "character" once again
5. **"Character 2" is being displayed**
6. Swipe to the left
7. Tap on Check button
8. "Character 2" is being displayed. But wait, that variable character should contain **"Character 1" instead!**

So why is it happening? It should display character 1 instead of character 2.

If you need more details, check out this video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gd6c7p0xvclixcr/IMG_0886.mov?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27934069/1135714

You need to workaround your way in by setting up multiple variables and edit their values when some `UIPageControllers` methods are activated.