# Get user swiping direction in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

These two methods `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController` of the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` don't tell the direction of the swipe.

The method `transitionCompleted` of the `UIPageViewController` delegate doesn't help us much either. It just tells if the page was fully swiped.

So what method should I use to detect exactly the user direction (left or right)?

Probably these two properties may help:

```
let directionForward = UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward
let directionReverse = UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Reverse
```

My code looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class ProView: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?

let characterImages = ["character1", "character2", "character1", "character2", "character1", "character2", "character1", "character2"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createPageViewController()
    setupPageControl()

    character = 1
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// Forward, check if this IS NOT the last controller
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    viewControllerAfterViewController ProView: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = ProView as PageItemController

        // Check if there is another view
        if itemController.itemIndex+1 < characterImages.count {

            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex+1)
        }

        return nil
}


// Check if this IS NOT the first controller
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    viewControllerBeforeViewController ProView: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let itemController = ProView as PageItemController

        if itemController.itemIndex < 0 {

            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex-1)
        }

        return nil
}

private func getItemController(itemIndex: Int) -> PageItemController? {

    if itemIndex < characterImages.count {
        let pageItemController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemController") as PageItemController
        pageItemController.itemIndex = itemIndex
        pageItemController.imageName = characterImages[itemIndex]
        return pageItemController
}

    return nil
}

func createPageViewController() {

    let pageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageController") as UIPageViewController
    pageController.dataSource = self
    pageController.delegate = self

    if characterImages.count > 0 {
        let firstController = getItemController(0)!
        let startingViewControllers: NSArray = [firstController]
        pageController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    pageViewController = pageController
    addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
    pageViewController?.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

func setupPageControl() {
    let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
    appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return characterImages.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {


}

// BETA

func pageViewController(PageItemController: UIPageViewController,
    didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
    previousViewControllers pageViewController: [AnyObject],
    transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
{

    if (!completed)
    {
        // You do nothing because whatever page you thought
        // the book was on before the gesture started is still the correct page
        return;
    }

    // This is where you would know the page number changed and handle it appropriately

    character = workaround

    }


}

class PageItemController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageCharacterChoose: UIImageView!

var itemIndex: Int = 0
var imageName: String = "" {
    didSet {

        if let imageView = imageCharacterChoose {imageCharacterChoose.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        }

    }
}
}
```

According to what pbasdf said,

```
var currentIndex: Int = 0
var nextIndex: Int = 0

func pageViewController(PageItemController: UIPageViewController,
    willTransitionToViewControllers pageViewController: [AnyObject]) {

        //                          pageViewController is the pending View Controller
        nextIndex = currentIndex

        // pageViewController...... how do I get its index?
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should use both the `willTransitionToViewControllers:` and the `didFinishAnimating:` delegate methods to work out whether the transition is forward or backward.  Declare a couple of index variables at the start of your class, say `currentIndex` and `nextIndex` (both `Int`).

In the `willTransitionToViewControllers` method, set the `nextIndex` equal to the `itemIndex` of the pending view controller:

**EDIT**

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionToViewControllers pendingViewControllers: [AnyObject]) {
    // the page view controller is about to transition to a new page, so take note
    // of the index of the page it will display.  (We can't update our currentIndex
    // yet, because the transition might not be completed - we will check in didFinishAnimating:)
    if let itemController = pendingViewControllers[0] as? PageItemController {
        nextIndex = itemController.itemIndex
    }
}
```

**END EDIT**

You can work out at this point whether the transition will be forward or backward: if `nextIndex` > `currentIndex`, then forward; if `nextIndex` < `currentIndex` then backward.  Then in `didFinishAnimating`, if `completed` is true (so it completed the transition to the next view controller), set `currentIndex` equal to `nextIndex` so you can use `currentIndex` wherever you need to indicate which page is currently on screen:

**EDIT**

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [AnyObject], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if (completed) {
        // the page view controller has successfully transitioned to the next view
        // controller, so we can update our currentIndex to the value we obtained 
        // in the willTransitionToViewControllers method:
        currentIndex = nextIndex

    }
}
```

Note that the first argument to these methods is the pageViewController (instance of UIPageViewController), not `pageItemController` which you have in your current code.

Finally, just to note: that enum you refer to (`UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection`) is used only in the `setViewControllers(_, direction:)` method.

**END EDIT**

Comment: Thank you very much for answering precisely my question. May you please explain how do I get the index of the pending viewController. You say "...equal to the itemIndex of the pending view controller", but I have on clue about how to do that. The rest of the answer is clear and nicely put - Thanks again!

Comment: @CeceXX I have updated my answer with some sample code.

Comment: I can't just THANK YOU enough!

Comment: I'd like to add here. There is a case when you move to next controller and immediately swipe back in opposite direction. In that case "willTransitionToViewControllers" won't be called on last swipe. So you have to add: if (completed) { ...} else { nextIndex = previousViewController.index }

Answer (score 4):

For my case, I was able to determine the swiping direction by using `func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [AnyObject], transitionCompleted completed: Bool)` only.

Here is how. Assume that you already have a way to reference the current index named `currentIndex`. In the above method, you already have the information about the `previousViewControllers` so that you can get the previous index named `previousIndex`.

Basically, here is the implementation inside the delegate method:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [AnyObject], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
  if completed {
    if previousIndex < currentIndex {   // forward

    }
    else if previousIndex > currentIndex {  // reverse

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a local array of the ViewControllers, you can use this `delegate` method:

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    guard let current = self.viewControllers?.first else {
        // TODO handle error
        return
    }

    guard let index = self.pages.firstIndex(of: current) else {
        // TODO handle error
        return
    }

    self.currentIndex = index
}
```

The `guard` statements should not fail, but just in case....

Answer (score 1):

Firstly in your viewControllerForIndex method assign viewcontroller.view.tag = index so that every viewcontroller.view has an assigned value

Have a currentIndex property which is initially assigned to that index of the viewcontroller which you have instantiated inside pageviewcontroller

Now in didFinishAnimating do the following

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        if !completed {
            return     // return if animation is not completed
        }
       let pCont = bottomDataContainer?.viewControllers?[0] as? CustomVC   //take 
       out current VC

        if currentIndex < pCont?.view.tag ?? 0 {
            topNavView.goToNextDate()
        }else{
            topNavView.goToPrevDate()
        }
        selectedIndex = pCont?.view.tag ?? 0
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by implementing the `UIScrollViewDelegate`:

```
var lastScrollDirection: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection?

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  let translation = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview)
    
  self.lastScrollDirection = translation.x < 0 ? .forward : .reverse
}
```

Assigning the delegate can be trickier. Here is what I used on a project:

```
func assignScrollDelegate(rootView: UIView) {
  for view in rootView.subviews {
    if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView {
      scrollView.delegate = self
    }
    else {
      assignScrollDelegate(rootView: view)
    }
  }
}
```

Call this when you have a reference to the `UIPageViewController`. For example, when your controller loads:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  self.assignScrollDelegate(rootView: self.pageController.view)
}
```

Comment: this is helpful but you may want to using `scrollViewDidEndDragging` rather than `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` to update your model

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to determine whether the user swiped forward or backward.

You need to use these two methods to provide the views before and after:

pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:

pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:

You can keep track of an index by adding a property to the viewControllers and then you can compare the pageIndexes.

Comment: How would I exactly do that? "You can keep track of an index by adding a property to the viewControllers and then you can compare the pageIndexes.". Thanks!

Comment: @CeceXX The view controller would have a property called pageIndex like this tutorial: http://www.makemegeek.com/uipageviewcontroller-example-ios/